# Date in LOV Query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, bi-publisher

I have a report that has two parameters, PM_DATE and PM_STOCK_ID. It's LOV query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM STOCK_COUNT
```

I want to filter the parameter PM_STOCK_ID based on the date which user specifies in date parameter. In the where clause of LOV I tried using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM STOCK_COUNT
WHERE TRUNC (SCHEDULE_DATE) = NVL (:PM_DATE, SCHEDULE_DATE)
```

but this didn't work.

I've also tried with a range using two parameters, P_SDATE (Start Date) and P_EDATE (End Date):

```
SELECT distinct id  FROM STOCK_COUNT
WHERE 
(TRUNC(SCHEDULE_DATE)) BETWEEN NVL(:P_SDATE, TRUNC(SCHEDULE_DATE)) AND NVL(:P_EDATE, TRUNC(SCHEDULE_DATE))
```

which gets error:

```
Parameter name: P_STOCK_ID Unparseable date: ""
```

How should I be doing this?

Comment: "this doesn't work" isn't very helpful. Why are you truncating `schedule_date` on the left hand side but not inside the NVL?

Comment: I have edited the answer with the new query. It's giving the error Parameter name: P_STOCK_ID Unparseable date: ""

Comment: `unparseable date` is a Java date conversion error, so the cause does not lie in the SQL you've posted here - especially as none of those queries use P_STOCK_ID, the parameter referenced in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

By just specifying the string :PM_DATE without a to_date function around it, you are getting implicit type conversion which is likely the root cause of the difficulty.